# Rails Routes And AJAX Requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-routing

I'm completely stuck right now and could really use some help.

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm using Ruby on Rails and I have two models. One is Exercises and one is Routines. A Routine is made up of various exercises. I currently have it setup so I can drag and drop from a list of exercises into a list of exercises for the current selected routine. To model this relationship I have an exercise_routine model that matches the exercise_id and the routine_id to model that they are associated. So, what I then do is when a user hits to save changes after all their dragging I use jQuery to assemble an array of all the exercise_id's in the list.

Now is the part where I'm stuck. I then want to pass that list to the create action of the exercise_routine controller. In that create action I would then compare that list of exercises with any that already existed and create any new associations and delete those that were removed.

I have seen multiple examples and none have worked out for me. So, I have gone back to just having my array of ids that I need to pass to the controller. My question at this point is how do I successfully pass that array as a parameter to the create action, or should I send this somewhere else, of the exercise_routine controller? I think the AJAX request I was using is fine, but the routing is really throwing me for a loop.

Any help is appreciated. If you need to see any code or anything I'll update as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
# send an ajax request with your ids
$.ajax
  url: "routines/1"
  type: "PUT",
  data: { exercice_ids: getExerciceIds() }
  success: function() {}


# update the routine exercice ids in the controller
def update
  @routine = Routine.find(params[:id])
  @routine.exercice_ids = params[:exercice_ids]
  @routine.save
end
```

This should work. You might want to have another action than `update`.

Comment: This answers helps clarify a bit. The update function has me confused. I have a has_many through for routines and exercises. So I have an array I can get that is @routines.exercises. I need to make entries in the table by creating a new Exercise_Routine which just passes in an exercise_id and a routine_id. My idea was to out together a list of existing exercises for the routine and then the new list. Compare the two and create new entries for new exercises added and go through and remove entries for ones no longer in the list. That is part of the confusion.

Comment: If you pass the exercice_ids, it means that they exists, right?

Comment: If you set `exercice_ids` on a routine, Rails will handle removing the exercices whose id are not present if the id list, and add the new ones.

Comment: So exercise_ids needs to be passed in as an array of values? I was doing it as a string and then splitting that into an array in the controller. Or does it not matter as long as I pass an array to that? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Pass it however you want. But with jquery, it's probably easier to get an array, and the ajax method will serialize it just fine. (you can use the `$.map` method from jquery to get your array of ids easily.

Comment: Ok so I have it setup like you said, but for some reason I'm getting a validation error. It says Routine can't be blank. Since routine is what is calling it how can the id for routine be blank? I checked it right before the call and it has an id and exists.

Comment: Where does it say that? Which model has this error?

Comment: Its coming on the exercise_routine model which validates that the exercise_id and routine_id are present when created.